# Hide iframe when Youtube video ends

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

Thank you everyone in advance.
I need some help hidding an iframe youtube video when it ends can someone guide me how to do that??

```
 <iframe id="promo_video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XzZudNOwkU8" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:228px;left:492px;" height="527" width="934" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

i need something like this but i cant find how to make it

```
 <script >
function myFunction()
{
    if (promo_video.end=positive)
    reload anotherother page


    }


</script>
```

Comment: Too broad with no details, what have you tried? What problems have you run into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this solution will work for you. The only change in solution is that you need only video id from iframe you have. Please refer the fiddle link mentioned below.

```
    <div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'XzZudNOwkU8', <!-- video id should be here. last component from video URL -->
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            $('#player').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }

</script>
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/smvora_4u/nprgpgek/1/)

Comment: Got anything same for vimeo videos?