# Remove a dynamically added iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube-data-api

Hi so I have a parent div that in any given time an iframe with an embed youtube video is added. This par works great but I want to remove the iframe once the video is done. I've tried using an EvenListener then tried a bind, both of which did not work.

```
function play_vid(id, par){
// id: youtube video id      par: id of parent div
var obj = {"video": {
    "value": '<iframe id="ytb-player" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' +id+'" frameborder="0" '+ 
     'allowFullScreen></iframe>'
    }}

$(par).html(obj.video.value);

$('#ytb-player').bind('onStateChange', function(e) {
   if (e.data === 0) {
    $(par).remove('#ytb-player');
   }
});
```

}

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're almost there but you need to use YT API to achieve this with `onStateChange`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036441/hide-iframe-when-youtube-video-ends)

Comment: Sorry my comment didn't go through ! Thx, it worked

Comment: Add answer to this question mentioning what worked for you and then accept that answer so people coming to seek help for related issue may find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! Using the YT API works with the code above!